# How to scan all pixel in square C#?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, canvas

I get `height` and `width` of an element on the website.

Example: Element `easelCanvas` with `height: 1000px` and `width: 600px`.

Note: I using Excel to easy imagine.
It must scan like this:

[image]

I do with code:

```
int width = 600, height = 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < width; i += 60)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j += 50)
    {

    }
}
```

First rows it scan from at position(0, 0) to final and go like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have creates one sample canvas it might be helpful to you ..

```
 var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");



var index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.height; i += 60)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < canvas.width; j += 50)
    {

ctx.strokeText("index"+index,j,i+15);
index++;

    }
}
```

[JsBin Link](http://jsbin.com/hileromuci/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Although I was using difference like Selenium and C# code but your question suggests an idea to resolve my problem. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Yeah, I was confused before posting answer because you not mentioned application type so..I just suggested you common answer..

Comment: Yup, thanks for that. I don't want mention with technology. It will be limit will many users.